# get the clicked class name using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the class name of a div which clicked. my there are few div tags like below.

```
<div id="car" class="ams-product car" data-ng-class="{ 'car-inactive ams-deactivated-product': carInactive() }" data-ng-click='getClass(); hide(); loadCarModule()'>
    <div class="ams-product-inner">
        <img class="product-img" data-ng-src="{{ carValidation()}}">
        <h3>Car</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim</p>
        <a href="#" class="add-this-product" data-ng-class="{ 'car-inactive': carInactive() }">+</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the class name or the id of top outer div(div id="car"). Please note that there are three divs like this. So I want to know which div is clicked.

Comment: Start by showing how this `car` got created from scope model to generate this view. In angular you rarely need to use element ID's because the elements get created from your scope and therefore you pass those data model  instances back into your functions in the html. You also don't worry about what class got clicked for the same reasons

Comment: ng-class is related to your model so you can know which class is active. I'm not sure to fully understand...

Comment: You can get class of course, very easy. However, most likely you should better take another approach with ngShow/ngIf, if you want to toggle divs or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check classes are set in the element which are apply using `ng-class`, you can simply check the variable/function which used to enable and disable `ng-class` like,

```
 $scope.getClass = function() {

      //if $scope.carInactive() is true then 
      //car-inactive & ams-deactivated-product classes apply to the element.

      console.log($scope.carInactive());
 };
```

Or you can use the old JavaScript way to get the class from the clicked element,

`ng-click` should be like pass the `$event` to clicked function,

```
...data-ng-click='getClass($event); hide(); loadCarModule()'>

 $scope.getClass = function(event) {
     console.log(event.srcElement.className);
 };
```

I think the **best way** you can do is **first one**, because in the second one if you click a child element of a outer div then `ng-click` will trigger, but when you trying to get the target of the event it will not always the outer div, because if you click on `h3` then target element is `h3`

Comment: pass the `$event` as a argument in `ng-click`

Comment: did you accept the event parameter in `getClass()` as `$scope.getClass = function(event) { ...`

Answer (score 1):

you should pass event variable in your html file

```
<div (click)="onClick($event)"></div>
```

then in your typescript file

you should use target and then id,className

```
onClick(e: any) {
    console.log(e.target.id, e.target.className);
}
```

Comment: This is an [tag:angularjs] question, not [tag:angular]

Comment: people searching on google for angular often end up in angularjs questions
this can be helpful to someone